# Can't authenticate with mongoenine to mongodb replicas

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

**1)** Before even setting replica sets in mongo i created admin user, with  "readWriteAnyDatabase", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin" roles.

**2)** Then i set my /etc/mongodb.conf configurations on all 3 servers.

```
 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
 logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
 logappend=true
 port = 27017
 auth = true
 replSet = test4
```

**3)** Initiated replicas, but got error 
(Do not remember exactly what the error was, but something related to that one of the server was not up. So i figured that it just can't authenticate)

```
config = {"_id" : "test4", "version" : 1, "members" : [{"_id" : 0,"host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"}, {"_id" : 1,"host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"}, {"_id":2,"host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"}]}

rs.initiate(config)
```

**4)** To solve the error, i generated keyFile and added keyFile authentication to my mongodb.conf file.

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
keyFile = /etc/keyFile
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true
port = 27017
auth = true
replSet = test4
```

And everything worked like a charm. Database copied itself over replicas. Admin user worked as expected too.

**5)** Then i created user with all needed permissions for other database i have, lets call it 'testdb' and user: notadmin, pass: notadmin.

But there is one strange thing i noticed. When i enter mongo in console i do not see replicas, until i log in admin database as an admin like this:

```
use admin
db.auth('admin', 'admin')
```

Then my console changes to test4:PRIMARY> or test4:SECONDARY> and i can perform actions with replicas. Guess it should be like this.

And everything works fine, if i insert data through pymongo library. Permissions work, admin user can insert into any database, given permissions, and notadmin user can insert into testdb.

But if i try to make the same thing with mongoengine models,

```
mongodsn = 'mongodb://notadmin:notadmin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017,xx.x.xx.xxx:27017,xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017/'
db_instance = mongoengine.connect('testdb', host=mongodsn, replicaSet='test4', readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
rt = ReconnectTest()
rt.content = 'item#{0:d}'.format(x)
rt.save()
```

i get authentication error:

> mongoengine.errors.OperationError: Could not save document (command
>   SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'notadmin'), ('nonce',
>   u'9ae2f85cd41f6c74'), ('key', u'8f814aa2434s4t2e0ff9bae03762e')])
>   failed: auth fails)

The only thing it permits me is from admin user to write to admin database. So something like this works:

```
mongodsn = 'mongodb://admin:admin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017,xx.x.xx.xxx:27017,xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017/'
db_instance = mongoengine.connect('admin', host=mongodsn, replicaSet='test4', readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
rt = ReconnectTest()
rt.content = 'item#{0:d}'.format(x)
rt.save()
```

**I am so confused, because mongoengine is just wrapper around pymongo. So how come i can do actions with pymongo, and can't do the same with mongoenige.  How do i authenticate with mongoengine to testdb ?**

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a user under the "testdb" database, as follows:

```
$ mongo admin -u <username> -p <password>
> use testdb
> db.addUser({user: <username>, pwd: <password>, roles: [<permissions>]})
```

Then trying to connect through mongoengine using the newly created user.

Also, add the database in the connection string, as such:

'mongodb://notadmin:notadmin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/**testdb**'

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't clear enough in my question.  I created notadmin user in testdb. And this user does not work either through mongoengine.

Comment: Ok, that's good. Have you tried specifying the database in the dsn string? E.g. mongodsn = 'mongodb://notadmin:notadmin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/testdb,xx.x.xx.xxx:27017,xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017/testdb'

Comment: Didn't help. 
But i figured something else up. 
 I can insert data in any table with pymongo and admin credentials (has all permissions).
 I cannot insert any data with pymongo and notadmin user, because it feels like it still tries firstly to authenticate itself in admin database, and ofcourse it fails, considering it is notadmin user.
 And with mongoengine i can insert only in admin database with admin user.